# DynamoDB Scan for a nested attribute values with NodeJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB with nested values inside. 
An Entry looks like the following: 
[image: Example Entry]

Now I would like to scan all entries in the database to find all entries with a specific episodeGuid.

I tried this code (and some variants), but always with 0 results.

```
    var params = {
        TableName: "myTableName",
        FilterExpression: "#episodeGuid = :myEpisode",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#episodeGuid': 'attributes.playbackInfo.episodeGuid',
        },
        // ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":myEpisode": { "S": "podlove-2018-12-06t13:07:10+00:00-f8a9b2963f313e5" } }
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":myEpisode": "podlove-2018-12-06t13:07:10+00:00-f8a9b2963f313e5" }
    };

    oDynamoDBClient.scan(params, async function (err, data) {
        console.log('read return');
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Can someone give me a hint how can I find my entries?

Comment: what is the error that your code is getting?

Comment: I doesn't get errors. Only Zero results

Answer (score 0):

The filter is looking for an attribute named `attributes.playbackInfo.episodeGuid` as opposed to a nested attribute.

To look for a nested attribute, the *expression* needs to contain to `.`.

```
FilterExpression: "#attributes.#playbackInfo.#episodeGuid = :myEpisode",
ExpressionAttributeNames: {
  '#attributes': 'attributes',
  '#playbackInfo': 'playbackInfo',
  '#episodeGuid': 'episodeGuid',
},
```